# Implement qsort() in terms of std::sort()

Tags: c++, algorithm, std, objective-c++, block

For stupid reasons, I'd like to write a function with the following signature (in which the `(^)` represents Apple's ["blocks"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_%28C_language_extension%29) extension to C++):

```
extern "C" my_qsort_b(void *arr, size_t nelem, size_t eltsize, int (^)(const void *, const void *));
```

where the function is implemented in terms of `std::sort`. (Note that I can't use `qsort` because it takes a function pointer, not a block pointer; and I can't use `qsort_b` because I might not have Apple's standard library. I won't accept answers that involve `qsort_b`.)

Is it possible to implement this function in C++ using `std::sort`?  Or do I have to write my own quicksort implementation from scratch?

Please provide working code. The devil is in the details here; I'm not asking "How do I use `std::sort`?"

Comment: What's the "void (^)" about?  Are you using "real" C++ ... or Microsoft CLI?

Comment: `void (^)(const void*,const void*)`??

Comment: Isn't the ^ "block" thing an Apple thing and not C++-CLI?

Comment: I'll be trolling and eventually tagging this question with `objective-c-blocks`.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Both of them, hence the confusion (and the opportunity for trolling).

Comment: Also note that you can [get a function pointer from a block](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure/blob/master/MABlockClosure.m) as well.

Comment: Based on past history, the OP is apparently using blocks on a Mac.  @Griwes - thank you for updating the tags :)

Comment: @paulsm4 Nevertheless the question could need some definite clarity over mere appearance.

Comment: For people who don't know what a block is, [this page says it's basically a lambda](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/)

Comment: I'm trying to imagine the "stupid reasons" behind this question.  This concept violates so much of what C++ is...

Comment: @H2C03 Yes, I meant Apple's blocks extension. I asked first in the C++ Lounge, and then came here later, and I guess I forgot to restart at the beginning of my explanation. :) Sorry for the vagueness. Anyway, I think you could reduce my example to just take a regular old function pointer and the fundamental difficulty would be the same; but I'll leave it as a block pointer for "historical reasons".

Comment: @H2C03 re [getting a function pointer from a block](https://github.com/mikeash/MABlockClosure/blob/master/MABlockClosure.m): That's if you're willing to link libffi and it works on your system (which I'm not 100% sure it does on iOS). But luckily that shouldn't be a necessary part of any solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this is harder than it seems it should be — although `std::sort` is clearly more powerful than `qsort`, the impedance mismatch between the two is sufficient to make implementing the latter in terms of the former a daunting task.

Still, it can be done. Here is a working implementation of `my_qsort_b` (here called `block_qsort`) that uses `std::sort` as the workhorse. The code is adapted from an implementation of `qsort` in terms of `std::sort` done as an exercise, and trivially modified to compare by invoking a block. The code is tested to compile and work with clang++ 3.3 on x86_64 Linux.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

struct Elem {
  char* location;
  size_t size;
  bool needs_deleting;
  Elem(char* location_, size_t size_):
    location(location_), size(size_), needs_deleting(false) {}
  Elem(const Elem& rhs): size(rhs.size) {
    location = new char[size];
    *this = rhs;
    needs_deleting = true;
  }
  Elem& operator=(const Elem& rhs) {
    memcpy(location, rhs.location, size);
    return *this;
  }
  ~Elem() {
    if (needs_deleting)
      delete[] location;
  }
};

struct Iter: public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, Elem> {
  Elem elem;

  Iter(char* location, size_t size): elem(location, size) {}
  // Must define custom copy/assignment to avoid copying of iterators
  // making copies of elem.
  Iter(const Iter& rhs): elem(rhs.elem.location, rhs.elem.size) {}
  Iter& operator=(const Iter& rhs) {elem.location = rhs.elem.location; return *this;}

  char* adjust(ptrdiff_t offset) const {
    return elem.location + ptrdiff_t(elem.size) * offset;
  }

  // Operations required for random iterator.
  Iter operator+(ptrdiff_t diff) const {return Iter(adjust(diff), elem.size);}
  Iter operator-(ptrdiff_t diff) const {return Iter(adjust(-diff), elem.size);}
  ptrdiff_t operator-(const Iter& rhs) const {
    return (elem.location - rhs.elem.location) / ptrdiff_t(elem.size);
  }
  Iter& operator++() {elem.location=adjust(1); return *this;}
  Iter& operator--() {elem.location=adjust(-1); return *this;}
  Iter operator++(int) {Iter old = *this; ++*this; return old;}
  Iter operator--(int) {Iter old = *this; --*this; return old;}
  bool operator!=(const Iter& rhs) const {return elem.location != rhs.elem.location;}
  bool operator==(const Iter& rhs) const {return elem.location == rhs.elem.location;}
  bool operator<(const Iter& rhs) const {return elem.location < rhs.elem.location;}

  Elem& operator*() {return elem;}
};

struct Cmp_adaptor {
  typedef int (^Qsort_comparator)(const void*, const void*);
  Qsort_comparator cmp;
  Cmp_adaptor(Qsort_comparator cmp_) : cmp(cmp_) {}
  bool operator()(const Elem& a, const Elem& b) {
    return cmp(a.location, b.location) < 0;
  }
};

void block_qsort(void* base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                 int (^compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
  Iter begin = Iter(static_cast<char*>(base), size);
  std::sort(begin, begin + nmemb, Cmp_adaptor(compar));
}
```

If `block_qsort` needs to be called from C, you can declare it `extern "C"`, since it uses no C++ features in its interface. To test the function, compile and run this additional code:

```
// test block_qsort

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // sort argv[1..argc].
  block_qsort(argv + 1, argc - 1, sizeof (char*),
              ^int (const void* a, const void* b) {
                return strcmp(*(char**) a, *(char**) b);
              });
  for (++argv; *argv; argv++)
    std::cout << *argv << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Minus a point for using `new`/`delete`, though; I wonder if that's possible to fix in a way that's portable and efficient. (C++11 might help.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone I doubt it can be done - the interface of `qsort` specifies array size to be specified at run-time, so common tricks like templating on the block size, or using `std::array` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

to use `std::sort`, you'd have to write an iterator class and a class that wraps the block in a functor object. Implementing quicksort by yourself seems like a shorter alternative.

BTW: the block should be returning bool, not void, right?

Comment: a class that wraps the block in a functor object cannot be passed as an `void (*)(const void *, const void *)`. Are you certain that it will work with `^`?  (I don't think it does, but I'm not certain enough to downvote)

Comment: @MooingDuck Maniek is saying to wrap the *given* block in a *new* functor object, and then pass that functor object to `std::sort`. This will work fine. The hard part for me is the "write an iterator class" part; but @Yakk's answer helps with that.

Comment: @Quuxplusone I looked up what "blocks" are, this answer makes so much more sense after reading that...

Answer (score 1):

Start with this:

```
struct memblockref {
  void* location;
  size_t size;
  memblockref( void* loc, size_t s ):location(loc), size(s) {}
  memblockref& operator=( memblockref const& right ) {
    Assert( size == right.size );
    memcpy( location, right.location, std::min( size, right.size ));
    return *this;
  }
private:
  memblockref( memblockref const& ) = delete; // or leave unimplemented in C++03
  memblockref() = delete; // or leave unimplemented in C++03
};
```

then use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html to create iterators of memblockref to your memory buffer.

Then turn the block into a function pointer, or wrap it in a lambda or functor, and call `std::sort`, where you call your block based comparison on the `location` field of the left and right `memblockref`.

You may have to specialize `swap` or `iter_swap` as well, but maybe not.

Comment: huh, I'd never heard of `iter_swap` before.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: Standard iterators have to be crazy heavyweight, though; hence the existence of Boost's "iterator facade". Looking for a way to reduce the boilerplate without Boost, I discovered [`std::rel_ops`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/rel_ops/), which is kind of cool. Too bad they didn't standardize the rest of [`boost::operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) while they were at it.

Comment: This implementation of `memblockref` might unfortunately be insufficient for use in `std::sort`. The sorting routine sometimes keeps a reference to an element taken out of the array using the copy constructor, and puts it somewhere else. (Maybe this is being done only for swapping, and specializing `swap` and/or `iter_swap` would fix it, as you mention. When writing the code for my answer, I had to implement a true copying copy constructor for my equivalent of `memblockref`.)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer just so this question stops showing up as "unanswered". There might have been a reason I didn't accept it in January, but I forget why now. Anyway, I'm no longer looking for a way to implement `qsort_b`, and these four answers seem to cover pretty much all the bases.

Comment: Well, this one was here first, and is decently detailed; but I accepted yours instead, now. (Both this and that lose at least one point for not implementing `swap` and/or move-assignment; I bet `std::sort` doesn't work very efficiently without a good `swap` function.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone Remember that for `qsort` we're only swapping chunks of memory, not sophisticated data structures. With that in mind, I don't think a custom `swap` would be significantly more efficient than a simple-minded one.